# jplayer after video redirect to url

Tags: jquery, html, jplayer

in a html page i'm looking for a way to redirect to a url after the end of the video
I've tryed this code without success (redirect event at the end)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
ready: function () {
$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
m4v: "intro.mp4",
poster: "intro.png"
}).jPlayer("play");
},
swfPath: "js",
supplied: "m4v",
size: {
width: "950px",
height: "320px",
cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
}
,
events:{
onComplete: function() {
window.location = "http://www.cnn.com";
}
},
});
});
//]]>
</script>
```

this code autoplay the video, but doesn't redirect after the playback.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution using ended event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4v: "intro.mp4",
                poster: "splashvideo.png"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "m4v",
        size: {
            width: "950px",
            height: "320px",
            cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
        }
        ,
   ended: function() {
           window.open("http://www.yoursite.com/welcome", "_self");

   },
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```